# Is there a way in a Razor Pages app to change the default starting route to an Area?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, .net-6.0

When you create an ASP.Net Core Web App with Individual Accounts it adds an Identity Area along with the regular Pages folder.
Since I don't want to be working between the Pages folder along with the Area folder, I want to create a Home Area that my app's default route "/" will route to.
I was able to accomplish this for the Index page by adding this to Program.cs:

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute("Home", "/Index", "");
});
```

Obviously, this just takes care of the single Index page, but if I wanted to have an About or Privacy page, I would have to add AreaPageRoutes for them as well. I tried a couple different things with `AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention` that I am too embarrassed to show here, but was ultimately unable to find out how to make it work.

Is it possible and secondly, is it bad practice, to map the default routing of Pages to a specific Area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [PageRouteModelConvention to change the attribute route](https://www.learnrazorpages.com/advanced/custom-route-conventions) for pages in an area:

```
public class CustomPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors.ToList())
        {
            selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template = selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template.Replace("Home/", "");
        }
    }
}
```

Generally, my advice regarding areas in Razor Page applications is don't use them. They add additional complexity for no real gain at all. You have already found yourself fighting against the framework as soon as you introduced your own area. QED.

The only place areas serve a real purpose is within Razor class libraries, so you have to live with an area when using the Identity UI. But you don't have to use the Identity UI. You can take code inspiration from it and implement your own version in your existing Pages folder.

Comment: That worked! Thanks alot for that code.
I actually had a feeling about just using folders for my features/areas under the umbrella of Pages, but since MS automatically puts Identity under an Areas folder, I assumed it was a convention.
Also, I haven't tried to modify the Identity pages since they moved them to Identity.UI library. It was much easier to customize those when they were pages that showed up in your solution.