# How to change ASP.NET Core area name in routing?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, razor-pages

In my project, I have an area called `Admin`. By default, the route to its pages is, for example, `/admin/reports/add`.

I want to change the URL for that area, so instead of `/admin/reports/add`, the URL will be `/secret/reports/add`. I don't want to change the folder name, just the URL (PS: I am using ASP.NET Core Razor pages).

I tried `app.MapAreaControllerRoute()`, `RazorPagesOptions`, etc.

Here is my `Program.cs` file:

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseStaticFiles();

app.UseRouting();

app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapRazorPages();

app.Run();
```

And this is the folder structure:

[image]

Comment: Can you please share some [mre]?

Comment: I've updated the description and added some details

Comment: That's a pretty standard setup, no reports or something like this here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for your answers. This one worked for me.

```cs
public class AdminToSecretPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
{
    public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
    {
        foreach (var selector in model.Selectors.Select(x => x.AttributeRouteModel))
        {
            if (selector?.Template is null)
            {
                continue;
            }
            
            selector.Template = selector.Template.Replace("Admin", "Secret");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Customizing routes are described in this Microsoft documentation [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/razor-pages/razor-pages-conventions?view=aspnetcore-7.0):

> Razor Pages conventions are configured using an AddRazorPages overload that configures RazorPagesOptions.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    options.Conventions.Add(...);
    options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention(
        "/Admin", "/Reports", model => { ... });
    options.Conventions.AddPageRoute(
        "/Contact", "TheContactPage/{text?}");
}
```

The set of [conventions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.applicationmodels.pageconventioncollection?view=aspnetcore-7.0) allow you to configure routes in your scenario for a specific page in an area, a specific folder in an area, or all routes in an area, regardless of where the endpoints reside under the area folder. I've added all three of these scenarios in the code snippet below. (The first two convention methods in the code snippet are commented out while the third changes all routes within the area.)

There are a few SO [posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74269471/mapareacontrollerroute-for-identity-area-in-net-core-6-does-not-work) that reference `options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention`. The method name infers that this method would address your scenario. It only targets routes for a subfolder with an area. The code snippet below compares it to adding a custom convention described at this SO [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70527369/is-there-a-way-in-a-razor-pages-app-to-change-the-default-starting-route-to-an-a), which targets routes in an area.

The code snippet references uses the following folder structure to reflect your scenario (with an addition of the `login.cshtml` Razor page):

[image]

Add the following to **Program.cs**

```
builder.Services.AddRazorPages(options =>
{
    // Specific page in area.
    // '/Admin/Login' still navigates to '/admin/login' while
    // '/Secret/Login' both navigate to '/secret/login'.
    // Both return the same Razor page.
    //options.Conventions.AddAreaPageRoute(areaName: "Admin", pageName: "/Login", route:"/secret/login");

    // Specific folder in area.
    // In the case below the 'Reports' folder is targeted.
    // The full path of the 'Reports' folder is: '/Areas/Admin/Pages/Reports'.
    // All routes within the 'Reports' folder will change
    // from '/Admin/Reports/' to '/Secret/Reports/'.
    // Navigating to '/Admin/Login' does not change. Navigating to '/Secrets/Login' fails.
    /*
    options.Conventions.AddAreaFolderRouteModelConvention("Admin", "/Reports/", model =>
     {
         model.Selectors.ToList().ForEach(selector =>
         {
             if (selector.AttributeRouteModel?.Template is null) { return; }
             selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template =
                 selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template.Replace("Admin/", "Secret/");
         });
     });
     */

    // Iterate through all endpoints; if an endpoint starts with
    // the folder name "Admin/", replace it with "Secret/".
    options.Conventions.Add(new AdminToSecretPageRouteModelConvention());
});
```

Add file **AdminToSecretPageRouteModelConvention.cs**

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ApplicationModels;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class AdminToSecretPageRouteModelConvention : IPageRouteModelConvention
    {
        public void Apply(PageRouteModel model)
        {
            foreach (SelectorModel selector in model.Selectors.ToList())
            {
                if (selector.AttributeRouteModel?.Template is null) { continue; }
                selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template =
                    selector.AttributeRouteModel.Template.Replace("Admin/", "Secret/");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you change Route area admin in whole Project:

add following code to the Configure method in your Application's Startup class or  Program.cs and customize your name are:

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
{
    endpoints.MapAreaControllerRoute(
                    name: "Admin",
                    areaName: "Admin",
                    pattern: "secret/{controller=Home}/{action=Index}");
});
```

Comment: thanks. I also tried this. doesn't help

Comment: Please add my code in program file before app.run